# How to execute a command after eating an item with custom NBT?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm looking for a way to execute a command for any player on my server who eats this specific enchanted beetroot which gives them this effect that makes them feel like they are on drugs (screenshots attached)

[The Beetroot](https://imgur.com/a/qePDc)

[The Command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJPPu.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

You can use a repeating command block with testfor to detect if someone is holding the beetroot. If it passes true, it can detect if a command linked to stat.eat.beetroot (?) increases to one, reset it to 0, and execute whatever commands you would like. I'll post redstone and commands later when I can get on Minecraft.

Comment: It's been three and a half years, have you had a chance to get on Minecraft yet?